# Creating multiple on the fly dynamic pages, from one page

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, facebook, facebook-sharer

I am building a video site, and am running into an issue where facebook seems to "cache" the scraping of my page, based on the fact that all my videos actually render on the same dynamic page, utilising a query string.

I am building my meta tags dynamically, from server side, and facebook scrape debug, gets all the right info... but every new video, seems to not be scraped. Facebook share does not see the correct tags. I have read in the docs that FB scrapes every 24 hours, but it will continue to scrape just this one page. (videos.aspx) ?

When I find that the facebook share does not see the info, I do a debug on that url (videos.aspx with query string), and after that, an obvious scrape has been issues on demand, and the share function gets the right info.

The facebook sahre does NOT, however, get the wrong video title, etc.. It seems to at least somehow get that from the page title, but its not seeing my preferred imag, from my meta tag.

- How do I create "dynamic" pages that don't exist, one for each video as it is rendered?

OR

- What are the preferred techniques to circumvent this?

Url's are in format: `http://www.example.com/tube.aspx?VideoSRC=xxx`

My final rendered tags in `<head></head>`:

```
<meta name="og:image" property="og:image" content="xxxurlxxx">
<meta name="og:url" property="og:url" content="xxxurlxxx">
<meta name="og:title" property="og:title" content="xxxNamexxx">
```

ASP Code:

```
    Dim FBmeta As New HtmlMeta
    With FBmeta
        .Name = "og:image"
        .Attributes.Add("property", .Name)
        .Content = "http://www.yellowtube.co.za/" & myVideoControlProperties.Poster
    End With
    Header.Controls.Add(FBmeta)

    FBmeta = New HtmlMeta
    With FBmeta
        .Name = "og:url"
        .Attributes.Add("property", .Name)
        .Content = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
    End With
    Header.Controls.Add(FBmeta)

    FBmeta = New HtmlMeta
    With FBmeta
        .Name = "og:title"
        .Attributes.Add("property", .Name)
        .Content = myVideoControlProperties.videoName
    End With
    Header.Controls.Add(FBmeta)
```

Comment: `http://example.com/videos.aspx?videoID=XXX`, like you would in any other web-based system...

Comment: @MarcB, not sure how to intemperate your comment..? that is what I am doing...

Comment: then you need to show some actual code, because right now you've just got a list of vague symptoms...

Comment: @MarcB, my above explanation is very thorough? All my code works, as is. I am looking for suggested methods, ideas here, to circumvent the issue at hand.

Comment: If your pages are created dynamically, then your titles should be too. Facebook is not going to scrape one title and one title only because `videos.aspx` happens to be the same in all the urls. it's going to see `videos.aspx?videoID=1`, `videos.aspx?video=2`, etc...  as completely different pages and scrape each one differently. So again, show some code, because right now what you've given us is nowhere near enough to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @MarcB, thanks for your last comment. I thought that it would scrape each url independently, but as stated, every other video, does not pick up the right pic when sharing, but when I crape that url with the debug tool, it then sees the right info when sharing immediately after.

Comment: Maybe I have an intermittent error somewhere, that skips the meta generation code? Will investigate more.

Comment: @MarcB, Added some code. Not sure what else to add.

Comment: Seems I had a possible intermittent error indeed, that skipped the meta generation code, "sometimes". That probably when facebook scraped. @MarcB, thanks for the "bounce off" regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I had a possible intermittent error indeed, that skipped the meta generation code, "sometimes". That probably when facebook scraped. @MarcB, thanks for the "bounce off" regarding this. –